# Why Lombok annotations are not working from shared jar?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I have created jar file which contains Hibernate entities along with DTOs. Every DTO has following annotations:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
```

I build this library using Gradle and use it in the Spring boot projects.
But the problem is all the above annotations are not working. No getter/setter, constructors etc are available in Spring boot project.

this is my entry in build.gradle file in Spring boot projects

```
implementation files('lib/xxx-entities-1.0.jar')
```

Annotation processing is enabled in both projects, Lombok is added in both. Still the problem occurs. I am using IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: If you're importing a jar it won't be compiled again so unless it is built using lombok's annotation processing the getters, setters etc. won't be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should inspect compiled classes in your jar containing entities and DTOs. If the getters and setters are not there along with the rest of expected Lombok-generated code then check whether annotation processor is applied when the sources are compiled.

As soon as you use Gradle I'd suggest to add this line into `dependencies` section of your build file (for the module where the entities and DTOs are kept):

```
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
```

So your `build.gradle` (for Gradle 7.2) should look like:

```
ext {
  lombokVersion = '1.18.22'
}

plugins {
  id 'java'
}

dependencies {
  compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
  annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"

  testCompileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
  testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
}
```